Error while testing code
Here is my solana todolist program
#![allow(clippy::result_large_err)]

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;

declare_id!("6u7Wzgps8X8Qjd5AaqaF5mpKdfZzSfNt2MaPjATf2Z6Y");

#[program]
pub mod todolist {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize_list(ctx: Context<InitializeList>, list_name: String) -> Result<()>{

      let todolist = &mut ctx.accounts.todolist;
      todolist.owner = *ctx.accounts.owner.key;
      todolist.list_name = list_name;
      todolist.task_count = 0;
      
      Ok(())
    }

    pub fn add_task(ctx: Context<AddTasks>, task: String) -> Result<()> {

      let todolist  = &mut ctx.accounts.todolist;
      let task_state = Task{
        description: task,
        is_completed: false,
      };

      todolist.tasks.push(task_state);
      todolist.task_count += 1;

      Ok(())
    }

    pub fn remove_task(ctx: Context<RemoveTask>, task_index: u32) -> Result<()> {

      let todolist = &mut ctx.accounts.todolist;

      if(task_index as usize) < todolist.tasks.len() {

        todolist.tasks.remove(task_index as usize);
        todolist.task_count -=1;

      } else {

        return Err(ErrorCode::TaskNotFound.into());

      }

      Ok(())
    }

    pub fn complete_task(ctx: Context<CompleteTask>, task_index: u32) -> Result<()> {

      let todolist = &mut ctx.accounts.todolist;

      if(task_index as usize) < todolist.tasks.len() {

        let task = &mut todolist.tasks[task_index as usize];
            task.is_completed = true;

      } else {

        return Err(ErrorCode::TaskNotFound.into());

      }

      Ok(())
    }

  
  
}

#[account]
pub struct Task{

  pub description: String,

  pub is_completed: bool,
}

#[account]
pub struct List {

  pub owner: Pubkey,
  
  pub list_name: String,

  pub tasks: Vec<Task>,

  pub task_count: u32,
}

impl List {
  pub const MAX_TASKS: usize = 10; // Adjust this based on your requirements
  pub const MAX_LEN_LIST_NAME: usize = 100; // Max length of list_name

  pub fn space() -> usize {
      8 + 32 + // Discriminator + Pubkey for owner
      4 + Self::MAX_LEN_LIST_NAME + // List name (4 bytes for length + max 100 bytes)
      4 + (Self::MAX_TASKS * 285) + // Vec<Task>: 4 bytes for length prefix + 50 tasks of 285 bytes each
      4 // u32 task_count
  }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(list_name: String)]
pub struct InitializeList<'info> {

  #[account(mut)]
  pub owner: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(
    init,
    payer = owner,
    space = List::space(),
    seeds = [list_name.as_bytes(), owner.key().as_ref()],
    bump
  )]
  pub todolist: Account<'info, List>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(list_name: String)]
pub struct AddTasks<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub owner: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(
    mut, 
    seeds = [list_name.as_bytes(), owner.key().as_ref()], 
    bump)]
    pub todolist: Account<'info, List>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(list_name: String)]
pub struct RemoveTask<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut, 
      seeds = [list_name.as_bytes(), owner.key().as_ref()], 
      bump)]
    pub todolist: Account<'info, List>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(list_name: String)]
pub struct CompleteTask<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub owner: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
      mut, 
      seeds = [list_name.as_bytes(), owner.key().as_ref()], 
      bump)]
    pub todolist: Account<'info, List>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[error_code]
pub enum ErrorCode {
    #[msg("Task not found in the ToDoList.")]
    TaskNotFound,
}

Here is my test script:
import { ProgramTestContext, startAnchor } from "solana-bankrun";
import { BankrunProvider } from "anchor-bankrun";
import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { Program } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { PublicKey, SystemProgram } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Todolist } from '../target/types/todolist';

const IDL = require("../target/idl/todolist.json");
const todolistAddress = new PublicKey("6u7Wzgps8X8Qjd5AaqaF5mpKdfZzSfNt2MaPjATf2Z6Y");

describe('todolist', () => {

  let context: ProgramTestContext;
  let provider;
  let todolistProgram: anchor.Program<Todolist>;


  beforeAll(async () => {
    context = await startAnchor("", [{ name: "todolist", programId: todolistAddress }], []);
    provider = new BankrunProvider(context);
    todolistProgram = new Program<Todolist>(
      IDL,
      provider
    );

    
  });

  it("Initialize ToDo List", async () => {

    // Initialize the ToDo list
    await todolistProgram.methods.initializeList("MyToDoList").rpc();

    let [listAddress] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("MyToDoList"), context.payer.publicKey.toBuffer()],
      todolistAddress
    );

    let list = await todolistProgram.account.list.fetch(listAddress);


    console.log(list);

    // Assertions
    expect(list.listName).toEqual("MyToDoList");
    expect(list.taskCount).toEqual(0);
  });

  it("Add Task", async () => {
    // Derive the PDA for the ToDoList, ensure it's consistent with InitializeList
    let [listAddress] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("MyToDoList"), context.payer.publicKey.toBuffer()],
      todolistAddress
    );
  
    // Call the addTask method and ensure correct accounts are passed
    await todolistProgram.methods.addTask("Go to gym").rpc();
  
    // Fetch the updated list account to verify the task was added
    let list = await todolistProgram.account.list.fetch(listAddress);
  
    console.log(list);
    expect(list.taskCount).toEqual(1);
    expect(list.tasks[0].description).toEqual("Go to gym");
  });
  

  

});


When i run the script I am getting this error:

Found a 'test' script in the Anchor.toml. Running it as a test suite!

Running test suite: "/Users/aliceho/Desktop/solana/todolist/anchor/Anchor.toml"

  console.warn
    bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)

    > 1 | import { ProgramTestContext, startAnchor } from "solana-bankrun";
        | ^
      2 | import { BankrunProvider } from "anchor-bankrun";
      3 | import * as anchor from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
      4 | import { Program } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';

      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/bigint-buffer/dist/node.js:10:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:10:20)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/solana-bankrun/solana-bankrun/index.ts:27:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (anchor/tests/todolist.spec.ts:1:1)


 RUNS  tests/todolist.spec.ts
[2024-10-17T10:12:33.473108000Z INFO  solana_program_test] "todolist" SBF program from target/deploy/todolist.so, modified 37 minutes, 26 seconds, 442 ms, 863 µs and 242 ns ago
[2024-10-17T10:12:33.473491000Z INFO  solana_program_test] "todolist" SBF program from target/deploy/todolist.so, modified 37 minutes, 26 seconds, 443 ms, 490 µs and 242 ns ago
[2024-10-17T10:12:33.497450000Z INFO  solana_program_test] Overriding account at 6u7Wzgps8X8Qjd5AaqaF5mpKdfZzSfNt2MaPjATf2Z6Y
[2024-10-17T10:12:33.563484000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program 6u7Wzgps8X8Qjd5AaqaF5mpKdfZzSfNt2MaPjATf2Z6Y invoke [1]
[2024-10-17T10:12:33.563855000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program log: Instruction: InitializeList
[2024-10-17T10:12:33.564192000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]
[2024-10-17T10:12:33.564212000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
[2024-10-17T10:12:33.564285000Z DEBUG solana_runtime::message_processor::stable_log] Program 6u7Wzgps8X8Qjd5AaqaF5mpKdfZzSfNt2MaPjATf2Z6Y consumed 10258 of 2
  console.log
    {
      owner: PublicKey [PublicKey(xPQn2LcfqueKxHhbDmYc9RDz974Cyp7BXZwvmWYx1G3)] {
        _bn: <BN: e30489310018a723936ea71ffefd32d77f96313de15508f2f428c2bed2ce790>
      },
      listName: 'MyToDoList',
      tasks: [],
      taskCount: 0
    }

      at anchor/tests/todolist.spec.ts:42:13

 FAIL  tests/todolist.spec.ts (8.955 s)
  todolist
    ✓ Initialize ToDo List (31 ms)
    ✕ Add Task (1 ms)

  ● todolist › Add Task

    Reached maximum depth for account resolution

      at AccountsResolver.resolve (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/accounts-resolver.ts:89:15)
      at MethodsBuilder.rpc (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/methods.ts:285:7)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.996 s, estimated 9 s
Ran all test suites.



I believe it could be because of missing to define accounts on anchor call.
Something like this could help
await todolistProgram.methods.addTask("Go to gym").accountsPartial({owner: context.payer.pubkey, todolist: listAddress}).rpc();

